# Why Python is running as 32 bit on 64 bit Windows 10 with 64-bit Python installed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python script that runs on Windows 10 Pro x64.

When I open Task Manager, it shows that Python is running as 32-bit application.

[image]

This is weird because:

- Python 3.12.2 is installed as 64-bit variant (double-checked)
- Installer got from [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.2/python-3.12.2-amd64.exe)
- This is the only Python instance installed on this PC

[image]

Script was launched via double-click on it (if this is important info)

Please, explain me:

- Why it is still shown as 32-bit in task manager? Or is it error of Task Manager?
- Is it possible to force running all python scripts as 64-bit? If yes: how?

**UPDATE / ANSWER**

- According to [this documentation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0397/#:%7E:text=The%20launcher%20that%20is%20installed,and%2064%2Dbit%20Windows%20installations.) it is the 32-bit launcher, but the Python will be still 64-bit version
- to bypass this, right click on the python scripts and select "Open with" and select there the 64-bit Python executable. Typically, something like this :`C:\Program Files\Python312\python.exe`, than when double-clicking the python script it will appear in task manager like this: 
  [image]
- do this only if this is the only instance of Python installed on PC

Comment: Haven't you installed like this **Windows installer (64-bit)** from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3120/?ref=upstract.com

Comment: @toyotaSupra yes, exactly **Windows installer (64-bit)**, but from here:  https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3122/

Comment: You had any other Python  older version on your pc?

Comment: Everything was deleted. But there NEVER  was 32-bit python on this PC.

Comment: That  is all I can troubleshooting. I cannot go further.

Comment: could you please clarify: how exactly do you determine that it "is running as 32-bit application"?

Comment: @FObersteiner : Task manager. Attached screenshots.

Comment: Your python launcher is 32-bit, but it runs 64-bit python. Btw. why to use python launcher at all?

Comment: @FlashThunder: It looks so... I'm just reading [this](https://peps.python.org/pep-0397/#:~:text=The%20launcher%20that%20is%20installed,and%2064%2Dbit%20Windows%20installations.) article on launcher. Could you put that as an answer?

Comment: Interesting... I never thought about this "convenience" launcher, never used it. Whilst yes, I'm occasionally on Windows, using Python. I would consider this obfuscation, not convenience. So after all, it seems I have been using computers for too long.

Comment: @FObersteiner It's convenient when you have multiple versions of Python installed (you can select version using command line argument, or it can pick one automatically based on shebang in the script you run with it).

Comment: If you select C:\Windows\py.exe and right-click it and go to Properties, what does it say about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Python launcher is 32-bit, but it runs 64-bit Python interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Run Python Scripts Explicitly: Instead of double-clicking on Python scripts, you can run them explicitly from the command prompt using the 64-bit version of Python. Open Command Prompt (cmd.exe), navigate to the directory containing your script, and run it using the 64-bit Python executable:

C:> "C:\path\to\python3.12.exe" your_script_name.py